# Load content from website to MATLAB including internal frames (iframe)

Tags: php, html, matlab, iframe

I'm using `urlread` in MATLAB to load the content of websites and then search that for further use.

However, I came across a site on which the content I need is located in a specific internal frame which is embedded in the *index.php* through `<iframe>`.

When I use `urlread` with the url of the file which is seemingly embedded in the main file, I still only get the content of that *index.php* instead of that of the *targetframecontent.php*.

I guess `urlread` might not be the correct tool for this or I might be overlooking other things which make my attempts unsuccessful. 
Is there a way to get the content of such an internal frame into MATLAB?

---

EDIT: A bit more precisely:

I would usually use the following to read in the content of a website to my MATLAB workspace:

```
data = urlread('http://[...]index.php')
```

But doing that I only get the content of the parent *index.php* and not that of the embedded *targetframecontent.php*. I figured that out when going through the websites source code, where the part of the website which includes the content I'm interested in gets loaded into a frame with:

```
<iframe src="http://[...]targetframecontent.php" width="850px" height="1000px" border="0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Because of that I tried to use `urlread` directly with the url which is loaded in the specific target frame.

However, when I did this I still got the same content as if I was still loading the *index.php*.
So it seems to redirect `urlread` back to *index.php* whenever I try to use the direct url of *targetframecontent.php*. That is also what happened when I tried to load *targetframecontent.php* in a browser.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `urlread` will fetch only whatever URL you give it. If you open the URL of the iframe in your browser, do you get the embedded content? If you can't predict the URL of 'targetframecontent.php', you'll need to parse out the `<iframe>` target manually. MATLAB might not be the best language for this...could you use another language to download the contents and feed it into MATLAB manually?

Comment: If I open the url of my target frame I still get to the main index.php.  It seems that I get redirected there automatically.

Comment: Can you share the URL of the page you're trying to extract information from, or is it internal? It sounds like they're doing some trickery.

Comment: [exp](http://www.sf.tv/sfmeteo/lokalprognosen/index.php?q=Genève) is an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the [site in question](http://www.sf.tv/sfmeteo/lokalprognosen/index.php?q=Gen%C3%A8ve) checks the Referrer of the HTTP request. Using `wget`, if you pass the `--referer` option, you can download the `<iframe>`:

```
$ wget --referer="http://www.sf.tv/sfmeteo/lokalprognosen/index.php?q=Gen%C3%A8ve" -O test_ref "http://www.sf.tv/sfmeteo/lokalprognosen/detailprognose.php?id=&q=Gen%C3%A8ve&max=&drs=0&kiosk=&js=&deeplink=&f="
$ cat test_ref
[...]
<body class="sf">

<!-- referrer:http://www.sf.tv/sfmeteo/lokal -->

    <script type="text/javascript"> <!-- 
        var keineprognose = '0'; 
        // -->
    </script>   


<p class="inv">
    <a href="#anker_cm">zum Inhalt</a><br />
</p>
```

However, if you `wget` without sending a referrer, you get:

```
wget -O test_noref "http://www.sf.tv/sfmeteo/lokalprognosen/detailprognose.php?id=&q=Gen%C3%A8ve&max=&drs=0&kiosk=&js=&deeplink=&f="
 <body class="sf" role="application">

<p class="inv">
    <a href="#anker_cm">zum Inhalt</a><br />
</p>
<!--googleoff: all-->    <div id="HEADWRAP" class="sf-header">
  <div class="INNERWRAP">
    <h1 class="inv">SF Schweizer Fernsehen - Navigation</h1>
```

Which is the original, parent page.

Therefore, to suck this into MATLAB, you'll need to set the `Referer` HTTP header. Unfortunately I don't have MATLAB in front of me right now, but this page looks like it gives a good introduction to how to send headers with MATLAB HTTP requests: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/expanding-urlreads-capabilities/

Edit: Because it's not super-obvious from that page, here's a link to the `urlread2` function, which also includes some examples: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35693-urlread2/content/urlread2.m

Comment: Thanks! It took me a while to figure out what exactly to do, but after a few tries it finally worked. Here is how I used `urlread2` and its the helper function `http_createHeader` in the end: `header = http_createHeader('referer', 'http://www.sf.tv/sfmeteo/lokalprognosen/index.php?q=Gen%C3%A8ve')
    data = urlread2('http://www.sf.tv/sfmeteo/lokalprognosen/detailprognose.php?q=Gen%C3%A8ve','', '', header)`